# Magento computed column value in 'filter_index'

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, column

I have Magento CE 1.9.2.1 installed in my site.

Now in the Invoice grid, I have calculated "Grand Total Excl. Tax" in the Grid's collection query and also set that as a column with the below query customization:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('invoice' => 'sales_flat_invoice'),
    'invoice.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', null)
    ->columns('(invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount) AS grand_excl_tax');
```

It shows fine, but when I try to filter the grid by that column, then it generates error as following:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoice.grand_excl_tax' in
>   'having clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AS `main_table`

My column code:

```
$this->addColumn('grand_excl_tax', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Amount Excl. Tax'),
    'index' => 'grand_excl_tax',
    ##'filter_index' => 'invoice.grand_excl_tax',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_applyMyFilter'),
    'type' => 'currency',
    'align' => 'right',
    'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
));
```

`_applyMyFilter` function code:

```
protected function _applyMyFilter(Varien_Data_Collection_Db $collection, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column)
{
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $field = $column->getIndex();
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $select->having("invoice.grand_excl_tax=?", $value['from']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please add below changes to your code.**

You need to add `GROUP BY entity_id`.

Add select query on collection like below.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('s' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT (o.grand_total - o.tax_amount) grand_excl_tax,'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/invoice') . ' AS o'
        . ' GROUP BY entity_id)')),
    "s.entity_id = main_table.entity_id",
    array('grand_excl_tax')
);
```

After that add `filter_index` in `addColumn`:

```
$this->addColumn('grand_excl_tax', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Amount Excl. Tax'),
    'index'     => 'grand_excl_tax',
    'filter_index' => 's.grand_excl_tax',
    'type'      => 'currency',
    'align'     => 'right',
    'currency'  => 'order_currency_code',
));
```

I am tested it and it's working fine form me, After applying this there is not any issue on grid filter.

Let me know still if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try, in the meanwhile can you answer my following question ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126308/magento-minicart-block-conflicts-with-custom-sidebar-block-in-right-side-flap

Comment: please apply this solution and let me know if you still face any issue,I will check you another issue whenever i get time,Thanks :)

Comment: Great use of the `filter_index` option, this is not a widely documented feature.

Comment: Hi @NitinVala, How make the same with this code plese         $collection->join(array('soa' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = "billing"', array('full_address' => 'CONCAT(soa.street, ",", soa.city, ",", soa.region, ",", soa.postcode, ",", soa.country_id)'), null, 'left');

Answer (score 0):

use this `_applyMyFilter` function for `filter_condition_callback`

```
protected function _applyMyFilter(Varien_Data_Collection_Db $collection, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column)
{

    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $field = $column->getIndex();
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $select->where("invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount>?", $value['from']);
    $select->where("invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount<?", $value['to']);
}
```

Comment: can you please provide this solution for magento2?